How would I calculate Win% across different maps
How would I automate Win% for each map?
I figured out how to count how many times a map was played use COUNTIF(), but idk how to have my sheet count wins per map. I was trying COUNTIFS() to have the function also check if the map was also a win but idk how to do that.
Here is a example of what I'm working with:



Map
Result




Map1
Win


Map2
Win


Map3
Lose


Map1
Lose


Map1
Lose


Map2
Win


Map4
Lose


Map2
Win



And this is what I'm trying to automate:



Map
Result




Map1
33.33%


Map2
100.00%


Map3
0.00%


Map4
0.00%




Is there a more generic way to describe this in the title?

You should use COUNTIFS twice to get the numerator and denominator of your data. You may use this:
=LET(a, UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)),
b, BYROW(a,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(B2:B,"Win",A2:A,x)/COUNTIFS(A2:A,x))),
HSTACK(a,b))

Output:
Use % formatting to view the data as percentage since the default result would be in decimal form. Manually add the headers for the output as it is not part of the formula provided in this answer.

References:

COUNTIFS
BYROW
TOCOL
LET


Use TOCOL() to refer full column like =HSTACK(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)),MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)),LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(A:A,x,B:B,"Win")/COUNTIFS(A:A,x)))).

I have added the TOCOL function to the formula that I have provided to cater to all the data on column a while ignoring empty cells.


Here's one approach via. PERCENTIF:
=map(unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,percentif(filter(B:B,A:A=Σ),"Win")}))



Another alternative is using the QUERY function;
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:B, COUNTIF(A2:A,A2:A),COUNTIFS(B2:B,"Win",A2:A,A2:A)},"Select Col1, Sum(Col4)/Sum(Col3) Where Col1 Is Not Null Group By Col1  Label Sum(Col4)/Sum(Col3) '' FORMAT Sum(Col4)/Sum(Col3) '0.00%'"))

.

